# When creating an association with Sequelize and Migrations, is the alias name absolute or changed to AliasId?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, migration, sequelize.js

I have a sequelize association like so in the Housing model:

```
Housing.belongsTo(models.User, {as : Owner});
```

When adding the column to the model and Migrations file, by this association, is the table going to be named "Owner" exactly like the Alias, or "OwnerId", as it associates on the Id key of the User table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be based on the key you used in the model definition for `sequelize.define()`. If you have a Model called `Owner` with a key value of `owner` then when you call `Housing.belongsTo()` it will add a column to the `Housing` model called `ownerId`. This referential column is used to query for the related rows which you can do using the generated helper methods like `house.getOwner()` - where `house` is a Model Instance.

If you have defined `underscored: true` for your model definition then the generated column will be `owner_id`.

Comment: I have another Model called "User", i just want to set an alias to the foreign key, so instead of it being called "UserId", it's called just  "Owner"

Should i use:

`Housing.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: {name: 'Owner'} });`

Instead?

Comment: If you want to override the automatic generation of the foreign key then you can specify it by passing in `foreignKey: 'Owner'` to the `belongsTo()` options.